# Replace pre-declared variables with a loop in Java - Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application for a friend of mine that is a football trainer.

He asked me to create an application that is more of a table to count the stats of the players. The image below should clear things up:

[Table of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJTZl.png)

As you can see, every time I press the upper left button I want to add a new player two a new row with a decrement button a counter and an increment button below each stat column.

I can currently do that but each player has 10 different column counters. So considering that I want to add 25 players for the maximum I should copy my code (250 times) with an incremented value in order to gain the same functionality for each player.

I've thought about using an array or a hashmap I'm just not sure what's the best practise to do it. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Pre-declared variables for one player:

```
private int counter1 = 0;
private int counter2 = 0;
private int counter3 = 0;
private int counter4 = 0;
private int counter5 = 0;
private int counter6 = 0;
private int counter7 = 0;
private int counter8 = 0;
private int counter9 = 0;
private int counter10 = 0;


private TextView textCounter1;
private TextView textCounter2;
private TextView textCounter3;
private TextView textCounter4;
private TextView textCounter5;
private TextView textCounter6;
private TextView textCounter7;
private TextView textCounter8;
private TextView textCounter9;
private TextView textCounter10;
```

Routine that needs to be copied 250 times:

```
if (playersAdded == 1) {

   //Set 1
   ImageButton decrementButton1 = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
   decrementButton1.setImageDrawable(decrementDrawableScaled);
   decrementButton1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

   textCounter1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   textCounter1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
   textCounter1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

   ImageButton incrementButton1 = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
   incrementButton1.setImageDrawable(incrementDrawableScaled);
   incrementButton1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

   decrementButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

      if (counter1 > 0) {
         counter1 -= 1;
         textCounter1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
          }
        }
      });

  incrementButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          counter1 += 1;
          textCounter1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
      }
  );
                        //End of Set 1
}
```

Comment: Use an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Or an [arraylist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make class Player. (Learn Object-oriented programming)
2. Make row for one player. (Learn how to create listView, [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) should help you, or just google android listView)
3. Make listView with players row.